# can we make speedometer apart from canvasa

Tags: canvas, activex

I have created and a page in which there is a 5 speedometer with the help of canvas .Its functionality is that ,it read the value from excel file and show values on speedometers..say we have 5 values in excel file  10,35,40,45 and 60 then  the first value  will be shown in first speedometer, second value will shown in second speedometer and it goes on as the value completes ..Now Canvas supports only IE9 and above .

```
           Now i want to integrate this page in tableau which supports only iE 7 or less
```

Here is my problem, now i cannot integrate that page to the tableau because it supports only ie 7 and less and canvas supports IE9 or above ...I want to make the speedometer without the canvas ,what are my options that i can do to make it work on IE7

And second thing is there is any restriction on ActiveX  like canvas have like it will work only in selected IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD this code in your 
 like this

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

this will make canvas to run on IE7..I guess this is your solution

Comment: Please explain, IE7 knows neither [canvas](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie07.html) nor [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so I'm totally puzzled on how this may work.

Comment: yes you are correct my friend @fvu..BUt it depends on browser mode that is, IE7 browser mode means that it will behave the same like the IE7 browser however it is running on IE8 browser but internally it is using IE7 browser engine. This is all handled by IE8 browser. and not even on IE7 we can work these things on ie6 with some changes. and for more you can refer to this [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm)

Comment: OP said `what are my options that i can do to make it work on IE7 ` and not `what are my options that i can do to make it work on IE8 in IE7 mode` that's why I was puzzled.  But as your answer seems to be what he needed, despite him commenting elsewhere `it work with only with IE8` which appeared to me as he needed real IE7 support ... Thanks for you clarification.

Comment: @fvu there is no way to work the canvas in IE7..if u have any suggestion to do that  ,then u can tell me it will be appreciated.You  are more experience than me  u can teach me something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)?  It is a canvas implementation for IE that was used pre IE9.  It does not contain all the features, but it may be your solution.

Instructions for use are [here](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions)

Comment: can you suggest me any other language or something that can built the speedometer ..and tell me one thing @J.Allen is there any chance that we can built it with html without canvas .. or without canvas is it possible to make the speedometer

Comment: You could look into animation.  Maybe just have different images of the speedometer that replace each other.  There are some advanced tools like Adobe Flash, but they can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I can only agree with what markE says, but I also understand that for certain corporate customers upgrading isn't an option yet.

One option that hasn't been mentioned yet is using SVG, by using the discontinued [Adobe SVG Viewer](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/svg/adobe-svg-viewer-download-area.html) to support older versions of IE.  For other browsers support is better [but far from perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Support_for_SVG_in_web_browsers).  But it could be enough for what you're trying to do.

There are a number of existing [SVG Speedometers](https://github.com/dejapong/Finger-Speedometer) available for inspiration.  Also have a look [here](http://www.inovista.com/samples/SamplesSVGcomponents.html).

A last remark: if my guess that you're working for a corporate customer is right, ActiveX will most likely not be an option or at least be quite painful - in many cases these people will have very restrictive policies in place wrt ActiveX usage, or even a complete ban.  Should you opt for that route, be sure to inform yourself very well on all the administrative hoops you'll have to jump through.